# How to capture the return value of java from ant build file

Tags: ant

I am calling a java method from the ant build file. I want to capture the output of the method i.e. return value into the ANT variable/property.

Answer (score 0):

The [ant java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) has several attributes that create a property :

> **resultproperty (= rc)** :  The name of a property in which the return code of
>   the command should be stored. Only of interest if failonerror=false
>   and if fork=true.
>  **outputproperty (= stdout)** :  The name of a property in
>   which the output of the command should be stored. Unless the error
>   stream is redirected to a separate file or stream, this property will
>   include the error output.
>  **errorproperty (= stderr)** : The name of a property
>   in which the standard error of the command should be stored.

Core ant has only properties but no variables. A property once set is immutable by design.
There are ways to overcome those restrictions, f.e. several ant addons or [ant script task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) with access to ant api. As a rule of thumb => overwriting properties should only be used for special cases.